# WP7 XNA: How to change size or style of SpriteFont fonts dynamically in code?

Tags: windows-phone-7, fonts, xna, spritefont

There seems no way to change font size or style in code, right?? It seems the only way is to duplicate the font files and load them all when program starts??

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SpriteFonts convert a font, with style, size, and other parameters, to a pixel-based format for use as a texture within XNA. Those pixels are static, so yes, there is no way to change them, short of looping through per pixel.

However there is scaling (though it won't look so great scaling larger) to help with size adjustments needed, plus you could, like you said, create multiple SpriteFont files from the same base font for different styles, and dynamically *choose* one of those sprite font "textures" within your code.

Beyond that, for true fully dynamic runtime usage, you'd need to essentially create these sprite font textures on the fly, in memory. This means you'd have to do what the SpriteFont Content Pipeline project does but at runtime instead. [This is possible in WinForms](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/winforms_series_2), but as far as I know not really an option for WP7 as you apparently are using.